# I am trying to develop a specific adapter for sqlite3 with node.js This is similar sails-mysql as devised. I do not know how to start

Tags: node.js

```
OracleDialect.prototype.describe = function (connection, collection, callback) {

    var tableName = this.normalizeTableName(collection.tableName); 
    var queries = [];
    queries[0] = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, NULLABLE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'";
    queries[1] = "SELECT index_name,COLUMN_NAME FROM user_ind_columns WHERE table_name = '" + tableName + "'";
    queries[2] = "SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner "
            + "FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols WHERE cols.table_name = '" + tableName
            + "' AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name AND cons.owner = cols.owner "
            + "ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position";

    asynk.each(queries, function (query, nextQuery) {
        connection.client.raw(query).asCallback(nextQuery);
    }).serie().done(function (results) {
      var schema = results[0];
      var indexes = results[1];
      var tablePrimaryKeys = results[2];
      if (schema.length === 0) {
        return callback({code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE', message: 'Table ' + tableName + ' doesn\'t exist.'}, null);
      }
      // Loop through Schema and attach extra attributes
      schema.forEach(function (attribute) {
          tablePrimaryKeys.forEach(function (pk) {
              // Set Primary Key Attribute
              if (attribute.COLUMN_NAME === pk.COLUMN_NAME) {
                  attribute.primaryKey = true;
                  // If also a number set auto increment attribute
                  if (attribute.DATA_TYPE === 'NUMBER') {
                      attribute.autoIncrement = true;
                  }
              }
          });
          // Set Unique Attribute
          if (attribute.NULLABLE === 'N') {
              attribute.required = true;
          }

      });
      // Loop Through Indexes and Add Properties
      indexes.forEach(function (index) {
          schema.forEach(function (attribute) {
              if (attribute.COLUMN_NAME === index.COLUMN_NAME)
              {
                  attribute.indexed = true;
              }
          });
      });
      //console.log("describe schema: ",schema);
      callback(null, schema);
    }).fail(function(err) {    
      return callback(err, null);
    });
};
```

I hope all my questions can be answered with a link to a good documentation!

Thank you!
I hope all my questions can be answered with a link to a good documentation!

this is for orcale adapter